# Breakable tcolorbox using listings color formatting breaks

Tags: latex, listings

I'm working on my school research paper about game design. In the research paper I explain some of the code using the tcolorbox and listings packages. When the source code block is to long it wraps around to the next page, which is intended, but the white color basic style of the listings turns black.

[image: The white text turns black when wrapped to new page]

I made an overleaf example to demonstrate the problem. https://www.overleaf.com/5972581994qgkvfwkxkhym

Also any text after the tcolorbox disappears.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] that includes everything necessary to compile instead of a code fragment?

Comment: Yes of course, working on it

Comment: I have fixed the problem with the colors now, but the problem with the text disappearing isn't solved yet...

Comment: I'm confused: In the overleaf link you shared the second page contains white code and text after the listing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QllLs.png Can you please point out what you would like to change exactly?